# One select instead two selects with where

Tags: sql

I have two similar select like this:

```
select sum(a)
from db
where date <= GETDATE()
group by id, id2

select sum(b)
from db
where date > GETDATE()
group by id, id2
```

I would like to simplify to one query, is it possible to write one select instead of this two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  One method is two columns using conditional aggregation:

```
select id, id2, sum(case when date <= getdate() then a end),
       sum(case when date > getdate() then a end)
from db
group by id, id2;
```

Another is separate rows:

```
select id, id2, (case when date <= getdate() then 'past' else 'future' end),
       sum(a)
from db
group by id, id2, (case when date <= getdate() then 'past' else 'future' end);
```